# Reinforcement learning, is normalizing the reward should also change the learning rate?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The reward range for my current environment is $[-10000, 5000]$, so currently I normalize the reward to $[-2, 1]$. Should I also change the learning rate?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like if you normalize the advantages  to  have  mean  of  0  and  a  standard deviation of 1, it effectively rescales the learning rate by a factor of 1/σ, where σ is the standard deviation of the empirical advantages.

So, if you want the learning rate to stay the same, you should indeed multiply it by σ.

Take a look in 4.1.2 here: http://rail.eecs.berkeley.edu/deeprlcourse-fa17/f17docs/hw2_final.pdf